# python : binary trees

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree

```
from tree import Node, leaf

def is_var(tree:Node)->bool:
    if type(tree.mark) == str:
        return True
    elif tree.mark == "+" or tree.mark == "*":
        return False
        

def is_val(tree:Node)->bool:
    if type(tree.mark) == int:
        return True

def show_node(tree:Node)->str:
    if is_var(tree) or is_val(tree):
        return str(tree.mark)
    else:
        #fill in

example = Node("+",Node("*", leaf(2),        #         +
                             leaf("x")),     #        / \                  
            leaf(5))                         #       *   5
                                             #      / \
                                             #     2   x 
assert show_node(leaf("x")) == "x"
assert show_node(leaf(2)) == "2" 
assert show_node(example) == "((2 * x) + 5)"
```

Can someone tell me how I could get the last assertion to work? The first two work fine but Im having trouble returning the last one.

Comment: What is it showing for `example`, and what debugging have you done to try and resolve it?

Comment: Can you add the code for `Node` and for `leaf`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate the strings for the left and right nodes
2. If the left node isn't a var or val, but parenthesis around its string.
3. Ditto for the right node.
4. Put them together with your current operation.

You should be able to write the code.